# Why does this simple .NET console app have so many threads?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

This simple program starts with 15 threads - according to the count. Sometimes during its lifetime it drops a few, but they come back.

```
class Program
 {
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
         while (true)
         {
             Console.WriteLine(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count);
             Thread.Sleep(500);
         }
     }
 }
```

I was expecting the process to just have one thread (and my intuition was backed up by [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.threads.aspx))

Without the debugger, the process has only (!) 4 threads. Surely any CLR stuff would be hidden from my process?

What count is this? Does the process really have that many threads? Why?

Comment: just out of curiosity - who do I upvote here? everyone's got the same answer :D

Comment: @obelix: if they all deserve an upvote, you could upvote them all. Your kind of question should be asked on MSO.

Comment: @obelix: they all make sense so they've all got an upvote from me. When I'm back in the office on Monday I'll check up a few details and give the most detailed, backed up answer the trophy.

Comment: @Richard - did not think it merited a full blown discussion on meta. ergo just a comment.

Comment: My console application has 16 (!!!) threads. Could it be because I'm using LINQ?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try running it outside the debugger (i.e. press Ctrl+F5 instead of F5). You should only see three threads - the main thread, the GC thread & the finalizer thread IIRC. The other threads you see are debugger-related threads.

Comment: Yes, main thread, GC, and finalizer are exactly what you will see. However you need to A) run outside the debugger and B) turn off Visual Studio Hosting Process which adds a thread or two.

Comment: do you have a link to an msdn article?

Comment: is the VS hosting process activated even if I'm in Release mode without running the process through VS? I still see 4 threads...

Comment: Thread 4 might be a ThreadPool thread for any asynchronous work that needs to be done. Just guessing, though.

Comment: Need an evidence, It is completely wrong, I have seen the process moves between 4-7 threads outside the debugger!!! it is a very simple console app with an infinite loop!

Answer (score 5):

If you run it without a debugger attached, there are significantly fewer threads. And those would presumably be the finalizer thread, and other house-keeping CLR stuff.

Answer (score 5):

Project + Properties, Debugging, untick "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process".  I can't discover what it is doing.  As soon as I tick the "Enabled unmanaged code debugging" option to try to get a peek at these threads, they no longer get started.  No clue.  But I'm sure it's for our benefit :)

Comment: I think the hosting process gives the debugger go faster stripes, or something like that.

Comment: I beleive the hosting process was designed to give faster startup times for debugging - when you debug, the relevant assemblies get loaded into the vshost process, rather than the debugger having to keep on creating/destroying new processes.

Comment: Nah, the hosting process is a custom hosted version of the CLR.  Mostly for security purposes.

Answer (score 4):

Try running it without the debugger (Visual Studio) attached (Ctrl+F5). You'll see that there will be less (probably 3) threads. Most of those threads have to do with the debugger.