# Single process C#.Net windows service is showing multiple thread in CPU resource monitor?

Tags: sql-server-2005, c#-4.0, sql-server-ce, windows-7-x64, epplus

I have developed a C#.Net windows service which is a single process.In this I'm using 2 third party Dlls one for ZIP(Ionic) and another for Excel(EPPlus).

The .EXE job is to:

1. Read SDF file
2. Write the SDF file data to SQL Server table
3. Generate Excel
4. Create ZIP

While monitoring this particular EXE in resource monitor it is showing 10 threads are running.

Note: I have not used any threading in this application.

Is OS making it 10 threads? If yes, how and why??

Comment: a third party API could be a source of spawned threads

Comment: How can I get confirmed? Where can I get source of EPPlus and Ionic?

Comment: I'm not sure what your development environment is like, but in VS 2010 professional, when I 'Break All' and navigate to Windows, Threads, I see the entire list of threads with the source listed under 'Location'

Comment: Yes I'm using VS 2010.Could you please tell me the steps("Break all" etc...), How can I see threads?

Comment: The Ionic source is located at http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#1639000 and it can spawn threads, it uses ThreadPool

Comment: Thanks.What is the easy-est method to see the thread name from the application,I mean which process is spawning these? I checked it from Debug-> Windows->threads, but its not clear.I can see only 4 threads in the main thread...Then from where another 6 threads are coming?? Its really confusing.

Comment: There should not be '4 threads in the main thread', I'm assuming you clicked the drop-down button and saw 4 entries for the main thread?  if so, what you are looking at is the call stack for that thread

Answer (score 0):

Related: [Why does this simple .NET console app have so many threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476642/why-does-this-simple-net-console-app-have-so-many-threads)

I'll use a simple console application in Visual Studio 2010 that adds a reference to an assembly that spawns a thread similar to what a 3rd party library could do.

A Windows Service may have different debugging techniques, and may have various additional threads running created by the system.

Simple Console

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      ClassLibrary1.Class1.StartThread();
      while (true)
      {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation("test2");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Simple API in separate class library assembly, added as a reference to the Console project

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
  public class Class1
  {
    public static void StartThread()
    {
      var t = new Task(() => {
        while(true)
        {
          System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
          System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation("test1");
        }
      });
      t.Start();
    }
  }
}
```

1. Start Debugging (F5)
2. From the Menu Debug, Select 'Break All'
3. From the Menu Debug, Select Windows then Threads

The following image shows :

- Main Thread, this is the console application
- ClassLibrary1.Class1.StartThread.AnonymousMethod_0, this is the thread started by the referenced assembly.  If Ionic or a 3Rd party API started a thread, you may see something related to its namespace.

[image: Break All Threads]