# Unable to read memory in web method

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, webforms

I'm getting this error in my application. I have a web method that I am calling from javascript.

The error I'm getting in the visual studio inspector:
[image]

The method signature:
[image]

The JSON I'm posting to the method:
[image]

It's a very obscure message to me. What do I do next?

Comment: if it`s possible could you provide complete  code of the GetPrajData ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is simple. I accidentally set the build configuration to release instead of debug which caused this behavior.

[What is the difference between Debug and Release in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367884/what-is-the-difference-between-debug-and-release-in-visual-studio)