# C# switch bad case

Tags: c#, debugging, switch-statement

I working on a Client/Server application who use encryption system, RSA to negociate a passphrase and AES to dialog, the encryption is ok, when the encryption has been negotiate , i set the public variable `encryption = Encrypt.AES;`, send a string to server and listen for his answer.
When client receive data i use a switch-statement by `encryption`

But, after a step-by-step debugging there is something strange, the switch-statement go to the wrong case.

[image: step-by-step screen]

Why the switch statement isn't working?

```
    public enum Encrypt
    {
        NONE, RSA, AES
    }
```

Comment: try on debug mode, why are you debugging on release mode? there may be some optimizations going wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by a "public variable"? Is it possible that you entered the switch statement prior to the field's value getting set? Also, is it possible that your program is functioning correctly but your symbols are out of sync so it looks like your debugging is at a different line than it really is executing?

Comment: check if the enum doesnt have the same int value assigned to different enums.

Answer (score 0):

For a unknown reason it's working in Debug mode
Thanks to M.kazem Akhgary :p

Comment: glad you made it work, please read this post, there is the reason. use release mode when you finally finished your program and you want to release it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367884/what-is-the-difference-between-debug-and-release-in-visual-studio