# Can I Create C# Standalone Application Than Runs Without Installing in Windows?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console-application, .net-4.5

I am building a standalone Windows C# console application using .NET Framework 4.5. Since I want it to run in background without command prompt appearing, the output type is set to 'Windows Application'.

Most answers I found in the internet is how to build application that doesn't require .NET Framework to be installed but in my case, I want the application to run without requiring users to install it in Windows.

I was able to do that if the target framework is .NET Core but when the target framework is .NET Framework, the published application has no .exe file but only application manifest & setup files which upon running will open an installation wizard.

Even when publishing the application in Visual Studio 2019, the publish wizard asks "How will users install the application?". Is that mean any console application using .NET  Framework shall be installed first before it can be executed? Many thanks in advance for any help/answer.

Comment: If you don't want a setup, simply share the executable of the application.

Comment: Yup, I just realize the executable file exists in the bin/debug folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about instead of publishing it just copy the .exe from the bin/debug folder? Then it should work without installing or publishing it. (if it is just 1 Assembly)

Comment: Thanks. It works. 
I knew from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367884/what-is-the-difference-between-debug-and-release-in-visual-studio

that in  Debug mode there are no optimizations while in Release mode there are optimizations. But the application is very small and simple so I think it won't affect much.