# Does Azure compile ASP.NET Core apps in RELEASE mode?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, blazor-server-side

When I publish my Blazor (server side) app to an Azure App Service, either through Visual Studio or a GitHub action, does Azure then compile it in DEBUG or RELEASE mode (i.e. which of those is defined)?

Comment: Easy to find out:  In your view: `#if(DEBUG) @("debug") #endif`

Comment: @mxmissile I'm hoping to learn what occurs across all different publishing scenarios. And if there's something I can/should do to set it. With that said, good point. I'll add a log statement that tells me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, when you try to deploy an WebApp (Blazor or any other template) to Azure app service, the default configuration is set to Release mode.

***Visual Studio:***

- Here I am trying to deploy Blazor Server app, you can see that my build configuration is set as Debug.

[image]

- I haven't changed any settings. After publishing the app, you can see the configuration is seen as Release.

[image]

- If you click on `Show all settings`,you can see the option to change under the settings.

[image]

***GitHub Actions.***

When we connect to Github Repo, by default `yaml` file will be generated.

- In preview, you can see the build configuration as `Release`.

[image]

- You can edit and change it to `Debug`in the `GitHub repo` => `Actions` => `Workflows`.

***or***

In `GitHub Repo` => `Code` =>`.github/workflows`

> I'm hoping to learn what occurs across all different publishing scenarios.

Refer [Debug mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/aspnet/site-behavior-performance/debug-mode-applications) and [What is the difference between Debug and Release in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367884/what-is-the-difference-between-debug-and-release-in-visual-studio) for more details