# Is Release Mode a special mode?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, configuration

I am using C++ in Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 and I tried copying Release mode in the configuration manager, and the copied configuration has exactly the same properties. However, it does not behave in the exact same way. The copied configuration is much slower.

I would like to copy the Release Mode configuration and then change the copied configuration from there.

Comment: Check the optimization settings. If your code is slower, it is more than likely that your copied configuration has a lower optimization setting than your release mode

Comment: [Release and Debug are just labels for different configurations](http://stackoverflow.com/a/938665/4342498)

Comment: @R_Kapp: The optimization settings are identical.

Comment: @Z0q no, there is no magic.  You missed something when you "copied it over".  My advice would be to use a computer difference tool on parts of the the project file and other parts of the project file.  And if you fail to find a difference, look harder.

Comment: @Yakk: I used the "Copy settings from" functionality of the configuration manager. I assume this would make an identical copy?

Comment: @Yakk: You are right.. I should have updated the library directories to use `$(Configuration)`

Comment: Actually, it's still behaving differently.

Comment: @Yakk: I used a compare tool. They are identical now. I have tried to rebuild. Still I get different results.

Comment: Did you rebuild the old one as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem.

For my application executable I made a custom profile in my graphics card options to use my dedicated instead of my integrated one. The newly created configuration was building the executable file in a different location.

Creating a profile for the newly created configuration solved the problem.