# Ms crm plugin .dll in debug/release vs2017

Tags: dynamics-crm

I am using vs2017 pro edition for MSCRM, after building my solution while taking the .dll file for plugin registration from bin\debug. My .dll file wasn't updated but checking in bin\release folder my .dll is modified by the build.

I tried multiple time to build the solution but debug path wasn't modified. Does this have impact?

1.So which one should we go for bin\debug or bin\release?

2.why isn't my bin\debug .dll not modified when it is build(previously I remember going for bin\debug)

3.what is difference and use of bin\debug and bin\release

Answer (score 1):

1. bin\debug for development; bin\release for deployment
2. There will be a dropdown in visual studio toolbar - debug/release mode. Verify that option - based on that, when you build your plugin solution the folder will get latest dll
3. [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/933739/7920473)