# Why does the execution result show a big difference in release mode and debug mode?

Tags: c, performance-testing

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include<time.h>
# include <limits.h>

int main() {
    clock_t start;
    long a = 0;
    long b = 0;

    start = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < INT_MAX; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < INT_MAX; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < INT_MAX; k++) {
                for (int q = 0; q < INT_MAX; q++) {
                    b = 1;
                }
            }
        }       
    }
    printf("%.5f\n", ((float)(clock() - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC));

    start = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < INT_MAX; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < INT_MAX; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < INT_MAX; k++) {
                a = 0;
                for (int q = 0; q < INT_MAX; q++) {
                    a += 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%.5f\n",((float)(clock()-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC));   
}
```

When I run in release mode, this shows the result immediately.
But when I run in Debug mode, it's not over.

I know that release mode is fast, but how can it be so fast?

Comment: An optimizing compiler will... well... optimize. In debug mode it won't go the same lengths. Why is it a shock?

Comment: What is the difference between release and debug mode?

Comment: @Sandeep read about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933739/what-is-the-difference-between-release-and-debug-modes-in-visual-studio

Comment: @CIsForCookies I was trying to ask what the questioner meant by debug and release mode as there was no mention of VS, but thanks for the link.

Answer (score 6):

When optimizing the compiler may see that this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < INT_MAX; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < INT_MAX; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < INT_MAX; k++) {
            for (int q = 0; q < INT_MAX; q++) {
                b = 1;
            }
        }
    }       
}
```

can simply be replaced by

```
b = 1;
```

Likewise the second loop block can be optimized away.

Further since `a` and `b` isn't used, the loops can be completely removed.

So your whole program may be optimized into something representing:

```
int main() {
    clock_t start;
    start = clock();
    printf("%.5f\n", ((float)(clock() - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC));
    start = clock();
    printf("%.5f\n",((float)(clock()-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC));   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To expand on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53096306/9658875), even if you do use **a** and **b**, like in a *printf* statement after the nested loops, the loops can still be optimized away. Why?

Your loop limit is a **constant** which is known at compile time. So the compiler will actually do the calculation of what **a** will be in the end at compile time.

Try reading in a loop limit value from the console, and you will see that the second loop now will not be optimized away anymore.

But do not use a huge number like MAX_INT, because that will take very, very long - even on a fast machine. That is why you observe this:

> But when I run in Debug mode, it's not over.

The program seems to run forever, right?

A number around 1000 will give you reasonable, measurable times.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I changed my answer acccordingly.