# In Visual Studio, where can you see what "Debug" and "Release" actually do?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, configuration, release

When you create a project in Visual Studio, you get a bar at the top, which gives you a button to press to launch your project.

However, I cannot figure out: **where is the configuration behind these buttons?** Where can I see (and edit) what actually happens (i.e. the scripts that run) when this button is pressed?

Other questions, for example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933739/what-is-the-difference-between-release-and-debug-modes-in-visual-studio) simply gloss over the fact that these are labels for configurations. However, I am asking: where is the precise list of commands that are run when the button is clicked?

[image: Visual Studio Debug/Release]