# vshost.exe file in Release folder?

Tags: c#, vshost.exe

Why there is a appname.vshost.exe file generated for the release version of my application? I might add that I'm using an external dll library and some unsafe code.

What's even more interesting, my application launched from Release folder does not work correctly (it works OK when launched from Debug folder).

It's bit hard to explain - feel free to ask if you need more info.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453841/how-to-turn-off-pdb-generation-and-vshost-for-all-release-builds/2454431#2454431

Answer (score 14):

For anyone else having the issue, it is probably because "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process" checkbox (in *Project Properties **->** "Debug" Tab*) is checked under your Release configuration.

You probably want it only checked under your Debug configuration so

1. just delete all files from your Release folder **OR** run *Clean* on the project;
2. then uncheck the checkbox
3. and build the project.

Comment: Right click on Startup Project -> Properties -> Choose Debug Tab -> Select "Release" configuration -> Disable checkbox

Comment: works for me! and I would be happy to find this answer 6-7 years ago

Answer (score 7):

From [David's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047643/vshost-exe-file-in-release-folder/3047658#3047658), perhaps the link at the bottom - [How to: Disable the Hosting Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185330(VS.80).aspx) might be what you're after if you actually want to get rid of it from your project's output.

Though it shouldn't do any harm to leave it on your machine; so just don't deploy it...

Answer (score -2):

Um, I know perfectly what this file is for, just don't understand why it was building in my Release folder while it's not normal behaviour (my VS never does that for my other projects).

Anyway, I managed to fix the problem using a good old trick - I just recreated the whole solution from scratch and vshost.exe file is only created in Debug folder, like it should. It seems that my previous solution was messed up somehow.

Issue closed.