# C# Remove/Amend Personal File Paths From Compiled Binaries

Tags: c#, reflection, compilation, cil

Using the `[CallerFilePath]` attribute in C# leads to the inclusion of full local file paths in the compiled CIL binaries, such as `C:\Users\MyName\Projects\Project\File.cs`.

> Is there a way of amending these strings in the compiled binaries? Perhaps as a build step to remove the "C:\Users\MyName\Projects\", but leave the remainder for logging purposes?

Off the top of my head, I can only think of `ildasm`'ing it, search & replacing, and then `ilasm`ing it - but this seems like a rather involved process.  I also came across references to the `STRINGTABLE` resource, but without any implementation details on how to post-process it.

There are a couple of suggested duplicates, including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371032/c-sharp-release-version-has-still-pdb-file), but I don't think this is a duplicate question as this one refers to the `[CallerFilePath]` attribute specifically, and not to debug-configuration related strings that point to `pdb` files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [the `pathMap` option for this](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/949). It should be available since Roslyn 1.1 and VS 2015 Update 1, though it's currently not documented.

In your specific case, you would add `<PathMap>C:\Users\MyName\Projects\Project=Project</PathMap>` to your .csproj file. Doing this means `[CallerFilePath]` will give you `Project\File.cs` instead of the whole path.

Comment: Fantastic - thanks!  Good to see that there are Roslyn options for these things.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48239792/is-it-possible-to-override-or-clear-the-debug-path-in-a-dll-build-with-new-cspro