# Is there any setting in the code, config or visual studio to NOT generate .PDB file in published code?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging, pdb-files

When I'm **publishing** the **.net code** via **visual studio** in **RELEASE** mode then it is creating **.PDB** files every time in the published folder.

**Expected Result: Is that. I don't want .PDB files to generate after code publish.**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# release version has still .pdb file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371032/c-sharp-release-version-has-still-pdb-file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you right-click the project in the Solution Explorer and choose Properties, then go to the Build tab and click the Advanced button, you will see an option to control whether to generate debugging information. Set this to None in your release configuration and no PDB file will be generated.

[image: Screenshot]