# Compiling in Debug Mode versus Release Mode

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Debug VS Release in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90871/debug-vs-release-in-net)

We send out releases almost weekly due to changes and bug fixes in our software.

Granted, that is problem not he best practice but I have a question about the builds.

Most of the builds are being left as Debug when built and then to the client.

What repercussions is/will this cause?  Will the program act differently if it is sent in debug mode?

I know there should be proper procedures for sending out releases but our company doesn't work in that reality. I'm trying to set up proper procedures for our customers getting releases so that less bugs go out to them.

Anyhow, any input, theories, or links would be appreciate.

Comment: So many variations of this question have been asked already, many times, so it would probably do you better just to search SO for `Debug vs. Release` mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically code compiled in debug mode will sometimes run slower (since it is not optimized), be bigger and contain information which would help alot if somebody wants to decompile/hack/change your code...

In some rare cases it might even behave differently...

Some interesting links:

- http://haacked.com/archive/2004/02/14/difference-between-debug-vs-release-build.aspx
- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/clr/thread/4de6861f-e723-4def-bcaf-aa717a3e1897/
- [Debug Visual Studio Release in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90871/debug-vs-release-in-net)
- [What is the difference between Release and Debug modes in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933739/what-is-difference-between-release-and-debug-modes-in-visual-studio)
- [How does building a project in Debug differ with in Release?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650425/how-does-building-a-project-in-debug-differ-with-in-release)
- http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/DebugRelease.aspx