# visual studio debug vs release mode

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Hi I'm using Visual studio 2010 and I can't figure out one thing.  I can debug and set breakpoints in release mode as well as debug mode.  so then what's the difference between the two?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Debug VS Release in .net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90871/debug-vs-release-in-net)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The difference is optimizations that the compiler applies in Release mode. You can place breakpoints if you have PDB files and by default they are generated even in Release mode.

Comment: So you can build projects and test them with Release mode in Visual Studio with no fear to skip a breakpoint or don't get debug info?

Answer (score 5):

here is a more detailed answer on [Scott Hanselmans Blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PermaLink.aspx?guid=a40c0d4f-66d0-4704-94f6-0efda4a44465)

But the root of the issue is that the code is compiled with more optimizations, you can still debug due to the creation of the pdb files.

Answer (score 3):

Newly allocated memory contains arbitrary values - whatever happened to be last sitting there. In release builds this is untouched. Debug builds in VS initialise newly allocated memory to 0xcdcdcdcd to flag is as "uninitialised".

Why would a *release* build fill memory with junk to make debugging easier? Release modes are just that - minimal extra overhead for actual releases.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to a Microsoft page titled [How to: Set Debug and Release Configurations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wx0123s5.aspx)

It discusses the difference between Debug and Release.  At the top of the page you can select different versions of Visual Studio.