# Project settings in "Release" vs. "Debug" mode

Tags: visual-studio-2010

In Visual Studio, you can specify different project properties for the *Release* and *Debug* modes. However, I usually want them to have the same project properties (i.e., the same includes and dependencies). Is there a way to copy the project properties of the *Debug* mode to the *Release* mode without making line-by-line changes?

Comment: There's no difference in includes and dependencies between Debug and Release. The differences are in the optimizations the compiler provides, and whether or not there is some detailed debugging information. If you're seeing differences between them other than compiler and linker flags (and some library names, if you're using C++), you've got something wrong. (Start a new project and compare the modes. See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832838/visual-studio-debug-vs-release-mode).)

Comment: I guess my question wasn't perfectly clear, please see Casey's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Use the Property manager to add a new property sheet, making any changes you want, and then "Add Existing" to the other mode.

The listed sheets are just links and when a sheet is changed in one place, it's changed in all. The inheritance is hierarchical (probably not a word...) moving from bottom to top with the actual project inherited last and the lowest property sheet the first.

In the property page for the project (right-click on the project in the Solution Explorer → *Properties*) set every element that is in bold to *"Inherit from parent or project defaults"*, and they will automatically inherit the properties from the next lowest property page in the property manager.