# release and debug

Tags: visual-studio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Debug/Release difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367884/debug-release-difference)

**what is diffrence between release and debug in vs projects**

Comment: may be this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90871/debug-vs-release-in-net and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/933739/what-is-difference-between-release-and-debug-modes-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 0):

Read http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/DebugRelease.aspx