# Visual Studio MSVCP110D.dll is missing

Tags: .net, windows, visual-studio, dll, frameworks

I recently downloaded and installed Visual Studio 2012 RC and made a program with it. However, if I try to run the compiled binary on another computer I get an error saying

> The program can't start because MSVCP110D.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

I don't get the error on my computer. I assume because Visual Studio installed that file for me. How do I compile the program, so that it'll run on a computer without that DLL file?

I discovered (correct me if I'm wrong) that this DLL file is a part of .NET Framework 4 or 4.5 Beta. So then I got to thinking that if I compile the program using a much earlier version of the Framework, say 2.0 or even 1.0, I would be able to work around this error.

Well, I was able to compile it using version 2.0 and 1.0 of the Framework, but I still get this error message. How do I compile a program that'll run without that DLL file file?

Oh and I get this error on ANY program I compile. Even a simple "Hello World" program. Again, I don't get this error on my machine since Visual Studio installed that file for me, just on other machines I try to run programs on.

Oh, I should probably also mention I'm running Visual Studio on a Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit machine, but I am compiling the programs on the Win32 platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the Dll is the Debug version of the C++ Runtime. If you search for your error and remove the 110D you will get a lot of similar errors from earlier versions. Are you compiling in `Release Mode` or `Debug Mode`

Comment: Aha!! Since you mentioned debug mode, I thought of compiling it in release mode. It totally works now. I can't believe I didn't think of that. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @EricTownsend - close your question.  Click the checkmark to the left of Mark's post.