# Separately running app runs correctly only when the VS2012 IDE is loaded with a project

Tags: vb.net

I have a VB.Net 2012 app (running directly, not in the IDE) for receiving scanned data that stays on top and retains focus.  Here is the code used to accomplish this:

```
 Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    Me.TopMost = True
    Me.TopMost = False
    Me.Activate()

    txtScanItem.Focus()

 End Sub
```

works perfectly, but, it only functions correctly if the IDE is running and has a project loaded, any project, and simply sitting idle (not running)

how does an IDE sitting idle cause the code to function properly?  perhaps some sequence of events at the OS level caused by the IDE when loading a project?  note that if the IDE is up but not loaded with a project the code fails to function correctly

Visual Studio Express 2012
Windows 7 Professional

thanks

Comment: Easy fix, just package the IDE and a dummy project to load to all your customers.

Comment: need the app to invoke when the PC is started.  the customer is only aware of the hand held bar code scanner

Comment: Windows actively prevents apps from stealing the foreground.  The rules are convoluted and documented in the MSDN library article for SetForegroundWindow.  Nevertheless, there's a dirty undocumented trick to cheat the rules.  And it is supported in VB.NET, use AppActivate(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id)  If your user complains about it then I'll deny you heard it from me.

Comment: still getting the same behavior.  i put the code you gave in the timer routine listed above (tried with and without my code) - is that correct?  thanks for the info - i'll check into the MSDN article...

Answer (score 0):

may be a long shot, but have you build the app in "Release" instead of "Debug"?

[Debug Visual Studio Release in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90871/debug-vs-release-in-net)