# Visual Studio release and debug

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I created an executable to run the most current build version in my development project for a tester. I was told where to locate the .exe in my bin directory but I'm still knew so I don't understand the technical differences between a release and debug build? I feel like they're very similar.

Comment: The .MSI part seems unrelated?

Comment: For the difference, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90871/debug-visual-studio-release-in-net (this didn't change in 2015)